# What is known about $\operatorname{card}_E(\mathrm{MST}\cap\mathrm{MWT})$?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, triangulations

It is a wellknown fact of computational geometry that the edges of **M**inimum-weight **S**panning **T**ree are also found in the **D**elaunay **T**riangulation of a planar pointset $\mathcal{P}$, i.e. $\operatorname{card}_E(\mathrm{MST(\mathcal{P})}\cap\mathrm{DT(\mathcal{P})}) = n-1$, where $\operatorname{card}_E$ denotes the cardinality of the edgeset.

**Question:**
is a similar result known for the [**M**inimum **W**eight **T**riangulation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiCtJrMv6ftAhVCzqQKHXLLCg8QFjADegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpage.mi.fu-berlin.de%2Fmulzer%2Fpubs%2Fmwt_TR_new.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1wOYfkehSkInga5CX0QmQb), ie. what is known about $$\operatorname{card}_E(\mathrm{MST(\mathcal{P})}\cap\mathrm{MWT(\mathcal{P})})$$